# Material design snacbar not working in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, snackbar

as code given by materialdesign.io

```
let action = MDCSnackbarMessageAction()
let actionHandler = {() in
    let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
    message.text = "Please complete your KYC detail"
    MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
 }
 action.handler = actionHandler
 action.title = "OK"
 message.action = action
```

I have tried everything , but this code of google materialdesign.io not working.

Comment: showing error in message.action

Comment: Define "not working". What is the error that it throws?

Comment: It won't resolve your issue, but I have used this https://github.com/luispadron/LPSnackbar for my App, and it is working like a charm (The more you know...)

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'message' @the4kman

Comment: @Balanced thanks, but I want to do work with this code.

Comment: @BaljinderKumar You defined `message` inside a handler and you try to access it outside of its scope.

Comment: @the4kman not working after declaration outside also. no snacker pop up

Comment: in my case i hadn't set action title. setting title fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snackbar like this

```
let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
message.text = "Item Closed"

let action = MDCSnackbarMessageAction()
let actionHandler = {() in

    let answerMessage = MDCSnackbarMessage()
    answerMessage.text = "Item Opened"
    MDCSnackbarManager.show(answerMessage)

}
action.handler = actionHandler
action.title = "UNDO"
message.action = action
MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use common method for alert function. 
use below code

```
static func showCustomeAlert(_ ViewController: UIViewController, messageA:String, MessageColor:String){
        let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
        message.text = messageA
        let myColors: [String: UIColor] = [
            "red": .red,
            "white": .white,
            "green" : UIColor.init(red: 70/255, green: 190/255, blue: 104/255, alpha: 1),
            "gray" : .gray
        ]
        MDCSnackbarMessageView.appearance().snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor = myColors[MessageColor]
        MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)


    }
```

write once use anywhere :D